# Как использовать индексатор реализуемый через интерфейс с параметрами?

Tags: c#, generics

Интерфейс:

```
 internal interface IMyDict<TKey, TValue>
 {
     // ...
     string this[int index] { get; }
     // ...
 }
```

Реализация:

```
 class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IMyDict<TKey, TValue>
 {
     string this[int i] => $"{keys[i]}: {values[i]}";
     string IMyDict<TKey, TValue>.this[int i] => $"{keys[i]}: {values[i]}";
     public override string ToString()
     {
         string str = "";
         if (length != 0)
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
             {
                 str = this[i] + ", ";
             }
         }
         return str;
     }
 }
```

Т.е. в реализации два индексатора - дополнительный и реализуемый. Хотелось бы понять как использовать реализуемый. В коде при переопределении метода ToString() я как раз вынужден из-за отсутствия этого знания использовать лишний(дополнительный) индексатор. Как использовать индексатор реализуемый через интерфейс с параметрами?

Comment: нужно привести объект к интерфейсу, тогда будет использована явная реализация

Comment: непонятно, зачем две одинаковые реализации

Comment: Спасибо, Grundy. Да, но я сперва пожалел скобки и не сразу сообразил. Приведение помогло:
((IMyDict<TKey, TValue>)this)[i]

Comment: в чем смысл иметь сразу две одинаковые реализации?

Comment: Первый - из-за ограничений реализации интерфейса, второй - для использования. В итоге конечно получился один.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно привести объект к интерфейсу, тогда будет использована явная реализация:

```
((IMyDict<TKey, TValue>)this)[i]
```

Comment: @DaemonHK, это ответ, а не дополнение к вопросу, см. комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: @insolor тогда может стоит обновить вопрос, хотя тогда он без ответа останется... ок, я понял